# react-native-google-places-autocomplete produces unpredictable results when the first item on the list is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik, google-places-autocomplete

I'm currently using the `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` within `Formik` and `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`. But, when the user clicks on the first item on the auto-suggested `listView`, it creates very unpredictable results.  It would either be

1) unresponsive,
2) `listView` closes and the address doesn't get selected, or
3) `listView` stays open, but submits the form even though the submit button for the form hasn't been pressed.

Oddly enough, when any other items on the list except for the first one is pressed, it produces desirable results.

```js
   const onFocusAddressAutoComplete = () => {
        Animated.timing(googlePlacesAnimation, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 300,
        }).start(() => {
            setFocus(true)
        })
    }

    const onBlurAddressAutoComplete = () => {
        setFocus(false)
        Animated.timing(googlePlacesAnimation, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 300,
        }).start()
    }

    const animatedPictureHeightStyle = {
        height: pictureHeightInterpolation,
        width: pictureHeightInterpolation,
        opacity: googlePlacesOpacityInterpolation,
    }

    const animatedHeightStyle = {
        height: introHeightInterpolation,
        opacity: googlePlacesOpacityInterpolation,
    }

    const animatedButtonHeightStyle = {
        height: buttonHeightInterpolation,
        opacity: googlePlacesOpacityInterpolation,
    }

    const onFocusProps = () => {
        onFocusAddressAutoComplete()
    }

    const onBlurProps = (param, callback) => {
        callback(param)
        onBlurAddressAutoComplete()
    }

    const submitHandler = input => {
        //submit logic
    }

    return (
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
            keyboardDismissMode={'on-drag'}
        >
            <Formik
                initialValues={{ address: '', introduction: '' }}
                onSubmit={submitHandler}
                validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
                    address: yup
                        .string()
                        .min(5)
                        .max(30)
                        .required(),
                    introduction: yup
                        .string()
                        .max(300),
                })}
            >
                {({ values, handleChange, errors, setFieldTouched, touched, isValid, handleSubmit }) => (

                    <FlatList
                        data={[
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                menu:
                                    <View style={styles.title}>
                                        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Sign up</Text>
                                        <TouchableHighlight
                                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Posting')}
                                            underlayColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'}
                                            activeOpacity={0.2}
                                        >
                                            <Icon
                                                name="x"
                                                size={moderateScale(30)}
                                                color={"black"}
                                            />
                                        </TouchableHighlight>
                                    </View>
                            },
                            {
                                id: 2,
                                menu:
                                    <View style={styles.fieldset}>
                                        <Text style={styles.addressLegend}>
                                            <Text style={{ color: '#FF5D4E' }}>* </Text>
                                            Your location for rental pickups
                                        </Text>
                                        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
                                            <GooglePlacesInput
                                                value={values.address}
                                                onBlur={() => onBlurProps('address', setFieldTouched)}
                                                onChangeTextFromFormik={handleChange('address')}
                                                onFocus={onFocusProps}
                                                focus={focus}
                                            />
                                        </View>
                                        {
                                            touched.address && errors.address &&
                                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.address}</Text>
                                        }
                                    </View>
                            },
                            {
                                id: 3,
                                menu:
                                    <Animated.View style={[styles.buttonContainer, animatedButtonHeightStyle]} >
                                        <TouchableHighlight
                                            disabled={!isValid || loading || called || signupLoading}
                                            onPress={handleSubmit}
                                            style={[styles.button, isSigninPressed && { borderColor: '#EAC0C0' }]}
                                            underlayColor={'#FF5D4E'}
                                            activeOpacity={0.2}
                                            onShowUnderlay={() => signinPressed(true)}
                                            onHideUnderlay={() => signinPressed(false)}
                                        >
                                            <Text style={[styles.buttonText, isSigninPressed && { color: 'white' }]}>Submit</Text>
                                        </TouchableHighlight>
                                    </Animated.View>
                            }
                        ]}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        scrollEnabled={false}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
                    />

                )
                }
            </Formik >
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    )
```

And the `GooglePlacesIput` component:

```js
export default GooglePlacesInput = ({
    onFocus,
    onBlur,
    onChangeTextFromFormik,
    value,
    addressRef,
    focus,
}) => {
    return (
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            ref={addressRef}
            placeholder='Search'
            minLength={1} // minimum length of text to search
            autoFocus={false}
            returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
            keyboardAppearance={'light'} // Can be left out for default keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
            listViewDisplayed={focus}   // true/false/undefined
            fetchDetails={true}
            textContentType={'fullStreetAddress'}
            autoCapitalize={'words'}
            selectionColor={'red'}
            clearButtonMode={'always'}
            autoCompleteType={'street-address'}
            // blurOnSubmit={false}
            renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
            onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                // const lat = JSON.stringify(details.geometry.location.lat)
                // const lng = JSON.stringify(details.geometry.location.lng)
                const { description, types } = data && data
                const address = {
                    lat: details.geometry.location.lat,
                    lng: details.geometry.location.lng,
                    location: description,
                    addressType: types,
                }
                onChangeTextFromFormik(address)
            }}
            textInputProps={{
                onChangeText: (text) => { },
                onFocus,
                onBlur,
            }}
            value={value}
            getDefaultValue={() => ''}
            query={{
                // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
                key: googleAPIKeyForAutocomplete,
                language: 'en', // language of the results
                // region: "CA",
                // types: '(cities)' // default: 'geocode'
                types: '', // default: 'geocode'
                location: '43.70011, -79.4163',
                radius: '100000', //100 km
                components: 'country:ca',
                strictbounds: true,
            }}
            styles={{
                container: {
                    width: '100%',
                },
                listView: {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 70,
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    flex: 1,
                    elevation: 3,
                    zIndex: 1000,
                    margin: 0,
                },
                textInputContainer: {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    marginTop: 0,
                    width: '100%',
                    padding: 0,
                    borderTopWidth: 0,
                    borderBottomWidth: 0,
                },
                textInput: {
                    backgroundColor: '#F9F5F4',
                    borderRadius: 50,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: height / 15,
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    marginRight: 0,
                    marginTop: 0,
                    paddingLeft: 30,
                    fontSize: 15,
                },
                description: {
                    // color: '#ac879a',
                    fontWeight: '300',
                },
                predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                    color: '#1faadb'
                }
            }}

            currentLocation={true} // Will add a 'Current location' button at the top of the predefined places list
            currentLocationLabel="Current location"
            nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
            GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
                // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
            }}
            GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
                // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
                rankby: 'distance',
                type: 'food'
            }}
            GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{ fields: 'geometry', }}
            // GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
            //     // available options for GooglePlacesDetails API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
            //     fields: 'formatted_address',
            // }}

            filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities
            predefinedPlaces={[]}
            enablePoweredByContainer={false}
            debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.
            renderLeftButton={() => { }}
            renderRightButton={() => { }}
        />
    )
}
```